# Is there any circuit simulator for Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, 21.04

I am using Ubuntu 21.04. Previously I used DSCH (of microwind) in other operating system. Now I am searching for circuit simulator for my Ubuntu.

Comment: Check this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1106672/66509 as starting point . For digital  electronics check list https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/electronics-digital . [SimulIDE](https://www.simulide.com/) is packaged at https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/simulide , maybe good variant.